# Setting certain ini values based on autodetected environment

Tags: php

My code detects the environment from multiple factors and sets all environment variables and constants based on the autodetected environment.

I have the following line in my code:

```
ini_set('zend.assertions',environment_among(PRODUCTION) ? -1 : 1);
```

Don't worry about `environment_among(PRODUCTION)`. The issue is that this line throws this warning: **Warning: zend.assertions may be completely enabled or disabled only in php.ini**

Since this setting depends on the environment as detected by the code, I can't put this setting in the server's php.ini file. How can I configure this locally? A solution that uses Composer is acceptable.

Comment: You might be able to have a custom `php.ini` in the app dir that overrides the main one but I've never done it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.assertions) and the [ticket](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71873) that updated the documentation, your php.ini should be set to `0` in order to dynamically change this at runtime. There are third-party assert libraries but the performance-optimized assert can only be handled by the runtime since it is a compilation step.